# How to write two decorator in file operations

Tags: python, function, file, file-io, decorator

I have csv file having contents below

`101,item_1
101,item_1`

if it is csv my below code will execute

```
import csv    
fName = input()
def read_csv(fName):
    try:
        with open(fName, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                print (row)

read_csv(fName)
```

Here how to write the exception in `decorator` function and call on the top of that.

**first decorator**

if `fName` not endswith `.txt` or `.csv` then it has to generate output `not accept`

**Second decorator**

if `fName = file.txt` text file then below operations has to taken care

```
def read_txt(fName):
    f = open(fName, "r")
    print(f.readline())
```

if csv then first function to execute and if txt next function to execute. How to achieve using decorator. I can put if conditon to achieve the situation, but that is not the case

My whole code without decorator is below

```
fName = input()
def read_csv(fName):
    if fName.endswith('.csv'):
        #print  ('hi')
        try:
            with open(fName, 'r') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                for row in reader:
                    print (row)
        except IOError:
            print ("Could not read file:", fName)
    #SECOND DECORATOR
    if fName.endswith('.txt'):
        f = open(fName, "r")
        print(f.readline())
    #FIRST DECORATOR
    if not(fName.endswith('.csv')) and not(fName.endswith('.txt')):
        print ('not accept')
read_csv(fName)
```

Comment: what excactly is the question?

Comment: if csv then first function to execute and if txt next function to execute. How to achieve using decorator

Comment: Is this some kind of homework? it is unclear why you need to use decorators for this, when there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this with decorators:

```
import functools


def check_arguments(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        fname = kwargs['fname']
        if not fname.endswith('.csv') and not fname.endswith('.txt'):
            print('not accept')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def set_file_processor(func):
    def read_csv(fname):
        print('read_csv', fname)

    def read_txt(fname):
        print('read_txt', fname)


    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        fname = kwargs['fname']
        if fname.endswith('.csv'):
            read_csv(fname)
        elif fname.endswith('.txt'):
            read_txt(fname)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@check_arguments
@set_file_processor
def process(fname):
    pass


process(fname='input.csv')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem doesn't seem to come under decorator but under factory pattern i.e. process differently based on the input file.

The below code is a very simple and basic Factory pattern solution to your problem, this should be modified accordingly as per your need,

```
import os
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class FileProcessor(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def process():
        pass

class TextFileProcessor(FileProcessor):
    def process(self, file_path):
        print("Text file processing goes here")


class CsvFileProcessor(FileProcessor):
    def process(self, file_path):
        print("CSV file processing goes here")


class DefaultFileProcessor(FileProcessor):
    def process(self, file_path):
        raise ValueError("File %s is not valid" % file_path)


class FileFactory:
    processors = {
        'txt': TextFileProcessor,
        'csv': CsvFileProcessor,
        'default': DefaultFileProcessor
    }

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            raise IOError("File not found")
        self.file_path = file_path

    def process(self):
        dot_splits = self.file_path.split(".")
        ext = dot_splits[-1] if len(dot_splits) > 1 else "default"
        ext = ext if ext in self.processors else "default"
        processor_class = self.processors.get(ext)

        return processor_class().process(self.file_path)


FileFactory(file_path).process()
```

In later stage if you would like to add json processor then it can also be done easily by adding

```
processors = {
    'txt': TextFileProcessor,
    'csv': CsvFileProcessor,
    'json': JsonFileProcessor,
    'default': DefaultFileProcessor
}
```

and creating new Json processor class,

```
class JsonFileProcessor(FileProcessor):
    def process(self, file_path):
        print("JSON file processing goes here")
```

Comment: PERFECTLY WORKING, but i need to implement using decorator

Comment: For the above-said problem, decorator is not at all a solution, the problem is there is a conditional function call- that is- if  CSV then one function and if itis not then another function should be invoked. Decorator is not supposed for this as it is designed for addressing common-repeatable problems (like checking authentication)/ readability. But if you are looking for a chain of decorators to handle different things for the same object please see this, https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-functions-exercise-17.php

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code and [this very useful guide](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators), here is a possible solution:

```
def read_file_decorator(fName):
    def read_csv():
        print('read_csv')
        with open(fName, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                print(row)

    def read_txt():
        print('read_txt')
        f = open(fName, 'r')
        for row in f:
            print(row)

    if fName.endswith('.csv'):
        return read_csv
    elif fName.endswith('.txt'):
        return read_txt
    else:
        return None

reader_function = read_file_decorator(fileName)
if reader_function != None:
    reader_function()
else:
    print('not accept')
```

I use a stateful decorator remembering the file name inside the reader function before actually executing it (in order not to pass it twice); and I use the fixed value `None` for invalid file types.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the requirements use of decorator would be an overkill of decorators. But if it's mandatory to implement this using decorator, this is how we can implement:

- We can create a dummy function called `read_file` and a decorator function called `reader`
- User will always call `read_file` with filename as argument and decorator function `reader` will check passed filename extension and call the required function - `read_csv` or `read_text`

```
def reader(fun):
    def wrapper(*args):
        fname = args[0]
        if fname.endswith('.csv'):
            read_csv(fname)
        elif fname.endswith('.txt'):
            read_text(fname)
        else:
            print('not accepted')
    return wrapper

def read_csv(fname):
    print('In read_csv()')

def read_text(fname):
    print('In read_text()')

@reader
def read_file(fname):
    pass


read_file('a.csv')
read_file('a.txt')
read_file('filename.py')
```

**Output**

```
In read_csv()
In read_text()
not accepted
```